# Reduct of a first-order structure

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I am trying to understand the notion of *reduct* in model theory. I found the following definition in Hodges's model theory book.

**Definition.** Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a first-order language and $\mathcal{L}'\subseteq \mathcal{L}$. Let $\mathcal{M}=(M,\dots)$ be an $\mathcal{L}$-structure. A structure $\mathcal{N}=(M,\dots)$ is called a reduct of $\mathcal{M}$ if $\mathcal{N}=\mathcal{M}|_{\mathcal{L}'}$.

This definition is clear for me. We just restrict $\mathcal{M}$ to $\mathcal{L}'$ and we get a reduct.  But if you google reduct you will find several papers in which there are some difference between their definition of reduct.  For example in one of them I found the following definition.

**Definition.** Let $\mathcal{M}=(M,\dots)$ be an $\mathcal{L}$-structure where $\mathcal{L}$ is a relational language.  An $\mathcal{L}'$-structure $\mathcal{N}=(M,\dots)$ is called a reduct of $\mathcal{M}$ if  every relation in $\mathcal{L}'$ is 0-definable in $\mathcal{L}$.

Could you explain why these definitions are the same?

Comment: Why do you believe the definition of "reduct" will be identical in similar (but very slightly different) settings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a bit of terminology I've always found annoying myself. The two definitions of "reduct" are **not** the same, although they are closely related. To distinguish them, I'll refer to the first as "reduct$_1$" and the second as "reduct$_2$."

The relation between them is this:

> $\mathcal{M}$ is a reduct$_2$ of $\mathcal{N}$ iff $\mathcal{M}$ is a reduct$_1$ of **some (parameter-free) definitional expansion of** $\mathcal{N}$.

That is, to get a reduct$_2$, we take the starting structure, *possibly add some additional relations/functions/constants, but only in a $(\emptyset-)$definable way*, and then remove some of the symbols. Every reduct$_1$ is a reduct$_2$, but the converse fails quite badly: e.g. $(\mathbb{N}, <)$ is a reduct$_2$, but not a reduct$_1$, of $(\mathbb{N},+)$.

The motivation for the terminology overload is that from a model-theoretic perspective, there is little difference between the "primitive" relations/functions/constants and the *definable* relations/functions/constants. For example, taking definitional expansions preserves: decidability, saturation, homogeneity, minimality and its various cousins, stability, ... So much of the time in model theory we lose nothing by conflating a given structure with its "full definitional expansion" (add *all* the $\emptyset-$definable relations/functions/constants), and then the two notions of "reduct" essentially coincide.

But that said, **it is still an overload of terminology** and can definitely lead to confusion if one is not careful. That's unfortunate, but that's the situation.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer Noah! So if consider $\mathcal{M}^*= (M, f_1, \dots, R_1, \dots, c_1,\dots)$ which is the full expansion of $\mathcal{M}$ obtained by adding all $\emptyset$-definable functions/relations/constants, then  the notion of reduct$_1$ and reduct$_2$ coincide. Right?